# How to add and remove gifs on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, materialize

I am using materialize to create an accordion collapsible on my page. I want to add gifs/images to my page when the collapsible header is clicked and want to remove them when that collapsible header is clicked again or another header is clicked.

I am able to add the gifs on click but have not been able to figure out how to remove them. I am using javascript and jquery.

Below is my code:

```
contentTitles = ["Test1", "Test2", "Test3"];
contentLinks = ["test1.gif", "test2.gif", "test3.gif"];

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.collapsible').collapsible();
  $('main').append('<ul data-collapsible="accordion"></ul>');
  $('ul').addClass('collapsible popout');

for (var j = 0; j < contentTitles.length; j++) {
  $('ul').append('<li></li>');
  // start the creation of the collapsible
  $('.collapsible').collapsible({
      accordion: false, // A setting that changes the collapsible behavior to expandable instead of the default accordion style
    });
  };

// create the collapsible
$('li').append('<div><i></i></div>');
$('li').append('<div><span></span></div>');
$('i').addClass('material-icons');
$('i').parent().addClass("collapsible-header hoverable");
$('span').parent().addClass("collapsible-body");

// adds the titles to each collapsible header
$('.collapsible-header').each(function(index) {
  $(this).html(contentTitles[index]);
})

// adds the gif urls to each collapsible body
$('.collapsible-header').on('click', function() {
  $('.collapsible-body').each(function(index) {
    $(this).html('<iframe class="gif" src=' + contentLinks[index] + '>');
  })
})

$('.collapsible-header').on('click', function() {
  $('.collapsible-body').html();
})

})
});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The .html() call just returns the html content of the element - it doesn't change it. If you want to empty the element, do this:

```
$('.collapsible-header').on('click', function() {
  $('.collapsible-body').html(""); //set HTML to be an empty string
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply

When I set the html to an empty string, the gif is removed before I am able to view any of them.

Comment: I think you're attaching two click handlers - one of them adds the gif, and the other immediately removes. I recommend just using one handler, and having it check whether there are gifs to remove, then you can add or remove as needed.